# How to read file content in textarea in JSP?

Tags: file, jsp, textarea

In below code, I am trying to read the file content in the text area in JSP it's displaying content but for each line it's creating new text areas. I need to print the whole content in one text area. Here is the code

```
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>

<%
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\windows\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Pricing\\build\\web\\image\\" + s + ""));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
%>

<textarea rows="10" cols="25"><%=sCurrentLine%></textarea>

<%
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
      <%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
      <%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>


        <%

           BufferedReader br = null;
           String myString = "";

     try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\windows\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Pricing\\build\\web\\image\\"+s+""));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        myString += sCurrentLine;
    }
         %>
          <textarea rows="10" cols="25"><%=myString%></textarea>
         <%

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


                %>
```

Comment: Don't down vote the correct answer.  You should be kicked of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'textarea' must be outside the while loop. Then you must append result to previous sCurrentLine. Something like this:

```
while ((sCurrentLine += br.readLine()) != null) {
```